# Outlook 2007 Backup to D:\Outlook Fails - Access Denied, Write-Protected or File In Use

Tags: permissions, microsoft-outlook-2007, write-protect

I can successfully save the Outlook PST file to the default location on the C drive (C:\Documents and Settings\user\ ... \Outlook) but when I change the backup save to directory to Outlook on the D drive I get the error: Cannot copy Outlook: Access is denied. Make sure the disk is not full or write protected and that the file is not currently in use.

I suppose it is not that crucial that I save this file here, but I have never seen this problem before and I have made this same change in the past.  I did some searching in this knowledge exchange as well as elsewhere on changing permissions, etc, but this didn't help.  I discovered that the folder on my D drive (called Outlook) is not write-protected and nor is it read-only, as I can save to and modify files in that directory, as well as rename and delete the directory itself.

At the time when I installed this version of Outlook, I used a previously saved Personal Folder (a backup PST file) and I thought having this still open in Outlook was causing the trouble.  But I closed it and still have the same problem.

I know this is probably a silly error on my part but I would like to figure it out.  I'm new to superuser, but the answers I see are usually very good, so I thought I would post my first question.

Edit:  the above setup is POP.  From a Google App setup at my work, I can export a PST file successfully to any directory I choose.  I am going to try the Import/Export method when I get home, to see if this works.  maybe it's the backup tool that is causing me trouble.

Comment: @nicorellius: Are you using the built-in Outlook export tool or doing this manually?

Comment: In Outlook:  File > Backup > Save Backup > Then Outlook tells you that the next time Outlook closes, the Backup will be saved.  I then close Outlook and the error above pops up.

Comment: Ssvarc - I can successfully export using the other option (see answer).  Your comment helped me think about how to get around my problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer: If I export using the Import/Export (File > Import and Export) option and then choose export to file and choose PST file, I can save my personal file to any directory I choose.  There must be something wrong with the backup tool.  Reinstalling the backup tool didn't help; still throws an access error.  I guess I have moved one step closer.  It is really bothersome that the backup tool isn't working like I want it to, though.

Tried something else with this question/answer.  I have two accounts setup in this Outlook 2007 setup:  a personal Gmail account, using IMAP, and a Google Apps Sync work account.  I tried creating a PST file using the backup tool and saving it to the D: drive and it worked.  Perhaps it's something with the way IMAP is set up?

OK, I repeated the test above with the Gmail IMAP account, and changed the directory to D:\Outlook\IMAP_gmail and the backup tool successfully saved the file.  Problem solved!